# Change bibliogrpahystyle to only add URL to bibliography when field "howpublished = {online}"

Tags: urls, bibliographystyle

I am looking to find a way to only add the URL to an entry in the bibliography IF the field `"howpublished = {online}"` for that bibentry. I am currently using the mla-good.bst which has the following entry:

```
FUNCTION {write.url}
{ url empty$
    { skip$ }
    { "\newline\urlprefix\url{" url * "}" * write$ newline$ }
  if$
}
```

I am very new to this, but shouldn't there just be a way to add something like if `"howpublished" == online print URL` ?

Thank you for your help!